# Get rid of Content-Disposition prefix added to files while uploading

Tags: php, curl, openstack

I write a script to upload files by php curl to oipenstack server. I got the token and the address to the upload directory.

When I use curl in CLI it works. But when I use my php script some code is added to the begining of the file so the file is changed. When the file is a video file it gets damaged and media players cannot play it anymore.

I have noticed the changes that are made by php curl. I compared the file before upload and after upload. The difference is some code added before the file content that I figured out in hex editor.

Let's watch them in screenshots (before / after):

[image: before]
[image: after]
So something about Content Disposition, name, filename are added there. I would like to fix my php curl script not to add any prefixes and change files at all. My php code is this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://abc-de.fghijklm.com/v1/AUTH_8a619275-f933-4da1-b289-0c06a1a2a3a4/bcd/drop93.avi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkaacb23cace324039a3be9c81b1b2b3b4";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$curlFile = curl_file_create ('./drop.avi');

$post = array (
    'file_contents' => $curlFile
);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);`

Comment: @smarber It did not help as well false is just default value of it.